# script command having odd effects when resizing terminal window

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

A little while ago I decided to log all my terminal activities by adding

```
script -t 0 "/Users/XXXXXXX/terminalLogs/log0$(date '+%y-%m-%d-%H:%M').txt"
```

to my .bash_profile file.  This worked generally as expected, but I've found a problem with resizing windows.

So I start my terminal window as so:

[image]

All fine... if I then resize the window and open a file using vim I get:

[image]

(you'll notice the the vim window is smaller than the terminal window)

If I type 'exit' to exit the logging, and resize I get the vim terminal I was expecting.

[image]

So I'm a little confused and it would be great if people could either explain what's happening, or if they could suggest a mod, or if people have better ideas for how I should be logging commands.  :(

Comment: It would be interesting, if you have the same behaviour using another terminal application, like iTerm2. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you resize a terminal emulator’s window, it adjusts its [pseudo terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) (“pty”) by making a TIOCSWINSZ (Terminal IO Control Set WINdow SiZe) ioctl system call. In turn, the kernel sends a SIGWINCH (WINdow CHange) signal to the foreground process group (e.g. the running instance of *Vim*) of that pty. Finally, the program(s) that received the SIGWINCH can use a TIOCGWINSZ (G for Get) ioctl to retrieve the new pty dimensions and redraw itself as appropriate.

Due to the way the *script* program works, the programs running “inside” the *script* session are actually running on a different pty from the pty created by the terminal emulator.

Consider this log:

```
% tty
/dev/ttys003
% script
Script started, output file is typescript
% tty
/dev/ttys004
% exit

Script done, output file is typescript
```

Initially, the shell is running on `ttys003`, but the shell that is started “inside” the *script* session is running on `ttys004`.

If I resized the terminal emulator window before exiting the *script* session, the terminal emulator would set the new size for `ttys003`, and the kernel would send a SIGWINCH to the *script* program (the foreground process of `ttys003`). Ideally, the *script* program would read the “outer” pty’s new dimensions and set the “inner” pty to have the same size. This would, in turn, cause the foreground process group of `ttys004` (i.e. your *Vim* instance) to receive a SIGWINCH.

Unfortunately, the version of *script* you are using ([Apple version’s from Lion](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-162/script/script.c)?) does not appear to pass along the change in window size (and unhandled SIGWINCH is effectively ignored). Other versions ([from util-linux-ng](https://gitorious.org/util-linux-ng/util-linux-ng/blobs/master/term-utils/script.c)) appear to do a better job handling SIGWINCH, but they may not be readily compilable on your system.

---

If you can stand to manually trigger the adaptation to the new size, then you can simply run the *resize* command (`/usr/X11/bin/resize`) inside the “inner” pty. It will query the terminal emulator for the appropriate size using escape sequences and then set the pty to the correct dimensions. In your stated scenario, you could do `:!resize` from inside your *Vim* instance to resize the “inner” pty (which Vim will notice once the `:!` command has finished).

If you want automatic resizing to work, then you will have to find a version of *script* that properly propagates pty dimension changes (by handling SIGWINCH and making the proper ioctls). Alternatively, you might be able to replace your `script` invocation with an invocation of the following Expect program:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
proc date {fmt} {
    clock format [clock seconds] -format $fmt
}
set file [if {$argc > 0} {lindex $argv 0} {list typescript}]

send_user "Script started, output file is $file\n"
log_file "$file"
send_log "Script started on [date %+]\n"

# WINCH code from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=865420
trap {
 set rows [stty rows]
 set cols [stty columns]
 stty rows $rows columns $cols < $spawn_out(slave,name)
} WINCH

spawn -noecho $env(SHELL)
interact

send_log "\nScript done on [date %+]\n"
log_file
send_user "Script done, output file is $file\n"
```

Give it a filename as its only argument:

```
 /path/to/script.expect "$HOME/terminalLogs/log0$(date '+%y-%m-%d-%H:%M').txt"
```

Comment: wow... that's quite the answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer but…

- According to its man page (`$ man script`), `script` doesn't seem to like interactive programs:

> Certain interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the
>   typescript file.  The script utility works best with commands that 
>   do not manipulate the screen. The results are meant to emulate a 
>   hardcopy terminal, not an addressable one.

- The "default" size is the same as your window's size when you start `script`.
- It's possible that `script` forcefully resets or disables a bunch of functions (like the ability to resize the window). The man page is silent about this subject but I think it would make sense to prevent resizing.